# Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert BugEvent@51a4f81 to BugEvent

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a swf called console which loads another swf name level.  Level has a function called `pauseLevel` which is called from console.  The `pauseLevel` function is called during `loadLevelDone` processing.  It is also called when message boxes are displayed or when the pause button is clicked.  The first time level is loaded the `pauseLevel` function works properly.  The second time it is loaded when `pauseLevel` is called during `loadLevelDone` it throws the following error.

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert
>   BugEvent@51a4f81 to BugEvent.     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()     at
>   flash.display::Stage/dispatchEvent()  at LevelMain/pauseLevel()   at
>   Main/pauseLevel()[C:\Users\Herb\Documents\Flash\BugEscape\console\code\Main.as:1811]
>     at
>   Main/loadLevelDone()[C:\Users\Herb\Documents\Flash\BugEscape\console\code\Main.as:1658]

This is the pauseLevel code:

```
public function pauseLevel():void
    {
        if (levelPaused){
            stage.dispatchEvent(new BugEvent(BugEvent.PAUSE_GAME, 0, 0, 3,"unpause"));
            levelPaused = false;
        }else{
            stage.dispatchEvent(new BugEvent(BugEvent.PAUSE_GAME, 0, 0, 3,"pause"));
            levelPaused = true;
        }
    }
```

This is my event handler:

```
public class BugEvent extends Event{

    public static const COIN_HIT: String = "cHit";
    public static const BOX_HIT: String = "bHit";
    public static const ADD_POINTS: String = "addPoints";
    public static const EXIT_HIT: String = "eHit";
    public static const JUMP: String = "jump";
    public static const KILL_BUG: String = "kBug";
    public static const KILL_PLAYER: String = "kPlayer";
    public static const REMOVE_BUG: String = "rBug";
    public static const REMOVE_BOX: String = "rBox";
    public static const PLAY_SX: String = "playSX";
    public static const DB_DONE: String = "dbDone";
    public static const PAUSE_GAME: String = "pauseGame";
    public var tileX:int;
    public var tileY:int;
    public var swapTo:int;
    public var killType:String;
    public var eventValue:int;

    public function BugEvent(type:String,tx:int,ty:int,st:int,kt:String="",ev:int = 0,bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false) 
    {
        tileX = tx;
        tileY = ty;
        swapTo = st;
        killType = kt;
        eventValue = ev;
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new BugEvent (type,tileX,tileY,swapTo,killType,eventValue, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have imported the same BugEvent, check if you have several "BugEvent" in your project.

For example, if you have

com.buglife.BugEvent
And 
com.buglife.event.BugEvent

It will be different class

Comment: thanks i didn't realize i had two loading one through the package and one directly imported when i was developing the class